# Use Java model in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, .net, wpf

I would like to use a java model. This is model of a human body. It has been written in Java, but I have to use it in ASP.NET. How can I do this? I tried the IKVM open source program. When I created a .dll I got a lot of not found warning. I have already installed the java sdk, and the eclipse. I could run java method under .NET. But I need a full model. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have IKVM dll's in the Global Assembly Cache?

Comment: It is a good question. I do not know. I add the ikvm dll's to the project references. I could start a easy java project under .NET. But I do not know how can I run a model project. There is a exception. The visual studio does not find java class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, - Could you please describe your setup in more detail?

What i gather from your question is that you have an ordinary ASPX page. In this page you would like to host a Java applet.

**One suggestion could be to show the applet in an iFrame (read: no need for special DLL's).**

In this case you could make a seperate HTML page embed the Applet as usual (:there are tons of howtos out there). And show it in the iFrame.

With this setup you might run in to issues with cross-side scripting, to fix this make sure that the host HTML page is loacted in the same domain as the ASPX page.

Good luck

Comment: It was a good idea. There is a other problem. We have to handle more events about the model. This model is a human body model. If the user click somewhere on the body, we have to show different things about that part. If I use a IFRAME how can I use the events.
in the other way. Can I convert a java model to .NET based model?